# How to display twemoji icon as cheat sheet in texbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using twemoji (https://github.com/twitter/twemoji) to insert icon in textarea comment. Here is my code when user select icon and insert to textarea.

```
$(document).on('click', '.emoji-list li img', function (e) {
     var icon = this.alt;
     $("#contentCmt").val(icon);
    twemoji.parse(document.getElementById('contentCmt'));
});
```

But when I'm selected icon smiley, the textarea is display as , I wanna to display as :smile: in cheat sheet. So how to do that?